# Origin of SSL identification string on certain HTTPS sites

Tags: browser, ssl, https

Some SSL protected sites have a fancy identification string in the browser navigation bar.  Where does it come from?  Is it the "Common Name" field in the CSR?

Here's an example:

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Common Name (CN) on a website SSL certificate is the hostname, ie, whatever part goes after https://

The entry you are seeing there comes from the Organisation (O) field in the cert.  If you view the details of the certificate in your preferred browser it should show you this.